# How can I create an object of objects in Golang with data taken from an array?

Tags: go

If I have this array:

```
type Person struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Name    string `json:"name"`
    Address string `json:"address"`
}

var Group = []Person{
    {
        ID:      "1",
        Name:    "Linda",
        Address: "London",
    },
    {
        ID:      "2",
        Name:    "George",
        Address: "Paris",
    },
    {
        ID:      "3",
        Name:    "John",
        Address: "Amsterdam",
    },
}
```

How can I generate an object of objects in each of which a particular value is the key and the rest of the key-value pairs are in, as in:

```
var Object = {
    Linda: {
        ID:      "1",
        Address: "London",
    },
    George: {
        ID:      "2",
        Address: "Paris",
    },
    John: {
        ID:      "3",
        Address: "Amsterdam",
    },
}
```

Not the smartest question in town I know, but please help!

Comment: The last snippet is not valid Go, so "object of objects" in what language? Or did you perhaps mean `map` by "object"?

Comment: @mkopriva I would do with any type that gets me this kind of output.

Comment: So it's not necessary to be valid Go? You just need that specific output, yes?

Comment: Please take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org). It only takes a few minutes and introduces all of the basic Go types and syntax.

Comment: @mkopriva It should be valid Go of course, but I can't figure the type. I was hopping someone does.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/pTECsaMXF4L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by Object here but one way to accomplish this would be via a `map`.

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    type Person struct {
        ID      string `json:"id"`
        Name    string `json:"name"`
        Address string `json:"address"`
    }

    var Group = []Person{
        {
            ID:      "1",
            Name:    "Linda",
            Address: "London",
        },
        {
            ID:      "2",
            Name:    "George",
            Address: "Paris",
        },
        {
            ID:      "3",
            Name:    "John",
            Address: "Amsterdam",
        },
    }

    personMap := map[string]Person{}

    for _, person := range Group {
        personMap[person.Name] = person
    }

    fmt.Println(personMap)
    // Outputs: map[George:{2 George Paris} John:{3 John Amsterdam} Linda:{1 Linda London}]
}
```

You could then access an a `Person` from the map via `personMap["Linda"]`